# Can't reference Entity Framework Core in .NET 5 and Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dotnet-cli

I'm using Visual Studio Code to build a class library with .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core.

However, I can't make reference to Entity Framework Core and I keep getting errors as if it doesn't exist.

This is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

All the package reference were included using *`dotnet add package`*

These are the attempts I already made:

- Restart Omni sharp
- Restore the packages (*`dotnet package restore`*)
- Use a lower version of Entity Framework Core (5.0.0)

*The specific problem and error message is here and was here all the time, so no other intelligent editor may close this question again:*

The result continues to be the same, **I get an error message on the *using* telling the *EntityFrameworkCore* namespace doesn't exist in the Microsoft namespace. However, the IntelliSense shows *EntityFrameworkCore*.**

What else could I try?

Comment: What errors? Post the actual code and the actual compilation errors. EF Core works fine. The program is compiled by the .NET SDK, not VS Code. You could use `dotnet build` and get the same result.

Comment: try to execute this ```dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore```

Comment: @H.Sarxha The package is already there. `dotnet add package` is the same as adding the PackageReference by hand. The OP said that `dotnet add` was already used, and the project file proves this

Comment: Did you try `dotnet build`? Do you get compilation errors?

Comment: Yes, I already tried dotnet build.  This is one class library inside a solution. When I execute dotnet build only for the class library, I receive no errors (what is another mystery for me), but if I try dotnet build on the solution, I receive all the .net core errors for the class library.

As I explained on the last paragraph, the main error is on the using statement, complaining EntityFrameworkCore doesn't exist in Microsoft namespace. Of course, as a result of this first error, no EF core type is recognized.

The package was included using dotnet add package.

Comment: Wow closed? Really?**
Some other things to try:
*Can you individually compile ONE project that depends on that project?
*Any chance of opening it up in Visual Studio to see if you get the same result? (Curious about that because of the number of "restart OmniSharp" solutions out in the wild.  
*Are all of the project targeting the same version of .NET (e.g. maybe one is explicit and not default...
**given who closed it I guess I won't act so shocked. :)

Comment: Hi Dennes, now that you've shared the solution in an email thread it would be great to a) retitle this question to be more useful for others that have the problem e.g. Package reference in a project not shared across dependent projects. b) explain what you discovered and how you solved it . That way, you can leave some breadcrumbs for the next person who has this experience.

Comment: @JulieLerman The problem is not solved yet, I'm still working on it. Although the projects compile, I received confirmation by e-mail this is not the usual .NET Core behavior, so it's not the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the comments of the question, although the error message from build and intellisense points to a specific .cs file, when I use *dotnet build* on this project no error is displayed.

However, the project is part of a solution where A references B which references C and C is the project with the error.

Building the solution results in errors pointing directly to project C, giving the wrong idea that C is the problem. It's not.

Following the recommendation on the comments and opening the solution in Visual Studio, it was possible to better identify the problem as being on the solution. Once this was done, the solution for the problem was found.

The solution is to add to the main project, A, the references included in project C. The same Entity Framework Core package in project C was included in project A as well and this solved the problem, allowing the solution to compile.

However, this is not a final and correct solution. I received many feedback advising this is not the usual behavior in .NET Core and I know it was not the usual behavior in older .NET versions as well. The mystery is still present: Why am I required to add to project A the same references than project C?

A clue to the mystery may be the fact project A is an Azure Function project. However, I don't know how this affects the entire solution.

Anyway, it's working with the fixed references.